# Failed To authenticate to specific firebase api project?

Tags: google-api, firebase-authentication, google-oauth, google-openid

the project that I am trying to automate is [This](https://play.clawee.com/login).

### Manual Logged in

When I click on Google logged-in it will redirect to manual login.
after I logged in successfully I can see there Post method

```
Request URL: https://www.googleapis.com/identitytoolkit/v3/relyingparty/verifyAssertion?key=AIzaSyDF-qMBES2pwjDAzWRRsu-FiAxZgJsBuIk
Request Method: POST

with the body
requestUri: "FirebaseappURL"
returnIdpCredential: true
returnSecureToken: true
sessionId: "SessionID???"
```

after that, it generates a Large respond

```
context: ""
displayName.
emailverified.
expiresIn:3600
federatedId:... 
firstName:. 
fullName:. 
idToken: <Token>
kind: "identitytoolkit#VerifyAssertionResponse"
lastName: ...
localId: <ID>
oauthAccessToken: <Token>  
oauthExpireIn: 3600
oauthIdToken:  <Token>
photoUrl: <url>
providerId: "google.com"
rawUserInfo: <long json>
refreshToken: <token>
```

I want to simulate it with post request with the postman
after that, I will transfer it to Script

### **What I tried**

### Google API Config

I went to [Google DashBoard](https://console.developers.google.com/apis/dashboard) Create Project.

Then I go to the OAuth consent screen and add my user as test users.

Add all the Clawee sites as authorizes.

Then I Went to Credentials and add Oauth 2.0 Client ID's of the Desktop client
and got his ClientID and SecretID

Now from postman, I went to

```
https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth?client_id=<ClientID>.apps.googleusercontent.com&response_type=code&scope=openid%20email&access_type=offline&redirect_uri=urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob
```

I got my auth-code

now I send a request to

```
https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token
```

with params clientid,secretId,authCode,grant_type
and get my Access Token + Refress Token

Now to check that, I navigate to
https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/userinfo?access_token="

I got My User Info... It works

Now I tried to use that Access Token
To login to Firebase app as they did
but because I using my Own token and not a manual login
I read about the "signInWithIdp" or "verifyCustomToken"
And I tried
with 'postBody': 'access_token=[My_Token]&providerId=google.com' or
token: [My_Token]

Both Failed...
What am I doing wrong?